# Twitter api exclude retweets in stream

Tags: node.js, twitter, bots

I'm using Node.js package `Twit` to stream tweets and currently it's including retweets as well but I don't want it to. My code looks like this:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#myhashtag' });
```

and I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#myhashtag' }, '-filter:retweets');
```

Answer (score 1):

After quite a research i think the '-filter:retweets' operator for query parameter has been outdated what worked for me was '-RT' operator.

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#myhashtag -RT' });
```

Answer (score 1):

when the tweet is a retweet, there is an existence of retweeted_status, otherwise it is undefined. maybe this will help:

```
if (tweet.retweeted_status == undefined) {

}
```

alternatively, another user proposed a function that might help:
https://github.com/ttezel/twit/issues/286#issuecomment-236315960

Answer (score 0):

The filter should be concatenated to the end of your query as shown below.

```
var stream = T.stream('statuses/filter', { track: '#myhashtag -filter:retweets' });
```

Comment: Thank you, just tried it though and the stream has stopped working

Comment: Also keep in mind that Twitter's streaming API only returns about 1% off all tweets.  So it is possible that the stream is working but nothing is returned for your particular hashtag.